# Disabling Gnome-3 right swipe gesture

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell-extension, gnome-shell

I am using GNOME version 3.18 on an Ubuntu desktop. It is to be used on a device with touch screen and I need to disable all gestures that show the gnome desktop.

I have used No Top-Left hot corner and MMOD panel extensions to disable the gestures, and it has been successful, except for a single gesture: A two finger swipe from the left edge of the screen to the right, that shows the overview.

I couldn't find anything that disables it. I have used Hide overview and Hide dash x extensions with no success. How can I disable that gesture?

Update: Here's the data @Redbob requested for:

```
cat /proc/version
Linux version 4.4.0-93-generic (buildd@lgw01-03) (gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) )
#116-Ubuntu SMP Fri Aug 11 21:17:51 UTC 2017
```

...

```
user@user-desktop:~$ xinput list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ A4Tech USB Mouse                          id=9    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ eGalax Inc. eGalaxTouch EXC7200-7746v1001 id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ eGalax Inc. eGalaxTouch EXC7200-7746v1001 Pen id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ SINO WEALTH USB KEYBOARD                  id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ SINO WEALTH USB KEYBOARD                  id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

...

```
user@user-desktop:~$ xinput list-props 12
Device 'eGalax Inc. eGalaxTouch EXC7200-7746v1001':
    Device Enabled (133):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (135): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    Device Accel Profile (266): 0
    Device Accel Constant Deceleration (267):   1.000000
    Device Accel Adaptive Deceleration (268):   1.000000
    Device Accel Velocity Scaling (269):    10.000000
    Device Product ID (254):    3823, 29185
    Device Node (255):  "/dev/input/event10"
    Evdev Axis Inversion (270): 0, 0
    Evdev Axis Calibration (271):   <no items>
    Evdev Axes Swap (272):  0
    Axis Labels (273):  "Abs MT Position X" (393), "Abs MT Position Y" (394), "None" (0), "None" (0)
    Button Labels (274):    "Button Unknown" (257), "Button Unknown" (257), "Button Unknown" (257), "Button Wheel Up" (139), "Button Wheel Down" (140)
    Evdev Scrolling Distance (275): 0, 0, 0
    Evdev Middle Button Emulation (276):    0
    Evdev Middle Button Timeout (277):  50
    Evdev Third Button Emulation (278): 0
    Evdev Third Button Emulation Timeout (279): 1000
    Evdev Third Button Emulation Button (280):  3
    Evdev Third Button Emulation Threshold (281):   20
    Evdev Wheel Emulation (282):    0
    Evdev Wheel Emulation Axes (283):   0, 0, 4, 5
    Evdev Wheel Emulation Inertia (284):    10
    Evdev Wheel Emulation Timeout (285):    200
    Evdev Wheel Emulation Button (286): 4
    Evdev Drag Lock Buttons (287):  0
```

...

```
user@user-desktop:~$ xinput list-props 13
Device 'eGalax Inc. eGalaxTouch EXC7200-7746v1001 Pen':
    Device Enabled (133):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (135): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    Device Accel Profile (266): 0
    Device Accel Constant Deceleration (267):   1.000000
    Device Accel Adaptive Deceleration (268):   1.000000
    Device Accel Velocity Scaling (269):    10.000000
    Device Product ID (254):    3823, 29185
    Device Node (255):  "/dev/input/event11"
    Evdev Axis Inversion (270): 0, 0
    Evdev Axis Calibration (271):   <no items>
    Evdev Axes Swap (272):  0
    Axis Labels (273):  "Abs X" (340), "Abs Y" (341)
    Button Labels (274):    "Button Unknown" (257), "Button Unknown" (257), "Button Unknown" (257), "Button Wheel Up" (139), "Button Wheel Down" (140), "Button Horiz Wheel Left" (141), "Button Horiz Wheel Right" (142)
    Evdev Scrolling Distance (275): 0, 0, 0
    Evdev Middle Button Emulation (276):    0
    Evdev Middle Button Timeout (277):  50
    Evdev Third Button Emulation (278): 0
    Evdev Third Button Emulation Timeout (279): 1000
    Evdev Third Button Emulation Button (280):  3
    Evdev Third Button Emulation Threshold (281):   20
    Evdev Wheel Emulation (282):    0
    Evdev Wheel Emulation Axes (283):   0, 0, 4, 5
    Evdev Wheel Emulation Inertia (284):    10
    Evdev Wheel Emulation Timeout (285):    200
    Evdev Wheel Emulation Button (286): 4
    Evdev Drag Lock Buttons (287):  0
user@user-desktop:~$
```

Comment: What is your device? Please edit your question and post output of `xinput list`. Let us see what can we help you. What's your Ubuntu version? Anote id from touchscreen device and post output of `xinput list-props <id>`.

Comment: @Redbob I don't have access to the device until saturday. But the touch controller is a generic one that didn't need any kind of driver installation. I will update the question as soon as possible and put the output here. But I was hoping to find a way in gnome configuration and not X11 configuration. But any solution is good anyway!

Comment: @Redbob I updated the post.

Answer (score 1):

The Gnome Shell Extension "[Disable Gestures](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1140/disable-gestures/)" disables all touch screen gestures AFAICT.

[Instructions on how to automate installation of the extension](https://askubuntu.com/a/1080306/391335).