# How to disable touchpad gestures in Gnome 3.18?

Tags: 16.04, gnome, touchpad, multi-touch

There are [certain gestures](https://help.gnome.org/misc/release-notes/3.14/touchscreen-gestures.html.en) that are part of Gnome itself, and I'd like to disable them since I've only ever activated them accidentally. [This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/959499/disabling-gnome-3-right-swipe-gesture) and [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1067078/how-do-you-disable-touchscreen-gestures-on-fedora-gnome) both address similar issues, but the first link points to [an extension for 3.20](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1140/disable-gestures/), and the second one would require creating an extension, which isn't too convenient of a fix.

Is there a way these gestures can be disabled, aside from the above methods?

Comment: touchpad or *touchscreen*?

Comment: @pomsky Touchpad. For some reason the link says touchscreen, but the three finger hold, double tap gesture to switch applications works.

Comment: All the links in your question relate to *touchscreen* though.

Comment: My issue is with the touchpad registering the application switch gesture, and the difficulty in disabling these gestures.