# Ubuntu 18.04 Touchscreen Kiosk – Disable Multi-Touch Gestures

Tags: gnome, 18.04, chromium, touchscreen, multi-touch

I'm running a kiosk touchscreen through [Chromium](https://www.chromium.org/). I've got it setup so that a Chromium application is running with the `--kiosk` flag, which prevents access to the OS.

The problem I have is with the multi-touch gestures. The gestures I would like to disable for GNOME are listed [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Multitouch#Supported_Gestures) and are 3 and 4 touch gestures. These gestures allow users to exit the Chromium kiosk application, which is obviously not what a user should be able to do.

My question is, how do I disable these multi-touch gestures?

If possible I would like to enable/disable these multi-touch gestures from the command line as part of my startup script.

Edit: I've recorded a [video demonstration](https://youtu.be/AhkxrwYTvlY) of the multi-touch gesture if the Ubuntu multi-touch document wasn't clear.

Comment: See https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1589520 → you should have a look in `gsettings` (e.g. `gsettings list-keys com.canonical.Unity.Gestures`).

Comment: @ponsfrilus 18.04 doesn't use Unity; GNOME is used instead. Is there something under org.gnome.*?

Comment: these settings are available in Ubuntu 18.04 running GNOME. You can check the full list with `gsettings list-schemas`. You can also search if it's feasible with `xinput`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems these gestures cannot be disabled with `gsettings`.

However, the Gnome Shell Extension "[Disable Gestures](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1140/disable-gestures/)" worked perfectly for me.

#### Automated Installation

I recently [added an installation command](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell/merge_requests/252) to `gnome-shell-extension-tool`. **This is not merged into upstream yet**. But the whole tool is just a single Python 3 script. So you can simply download and use my patched version of the file and run the following to install and enable `disable-gestures@mattbell.com.au`:

```bash
# Download extension
wget "https://extensions.gnome.org/extension-data/disable-gestures%40mattbell.com.au.v2.shell-extension.zip"

# Install extension
gnome-shell-extension-tool -i disable-gestures@mattbell.com.au.*.zip

# Enable extension
gnome-shell-extension-tool -e disable-gestures@mattbell.com.au
```

Comment: I have seen this, but is there a way to automate the installation of this extension as part of my provisioning script?

Comment: @Enijar I added installation instructions.

Comment: I'm getting `gnome-shell-extension-tool: error: no such option: -i`

Comment: @JonathanTuzman Did you use my patched version of `gnome-shell-extension-tool`? My changes were never merged into the upstream version, so the `-i` option is not available there.

Comment: Hi, I'm facing the same problem OP was, but I'm not able to get rid of this behavior. I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 with this disable-gestures extension but nothing has changed. I'm getting increasingly frustrated with this. @Enijar did you finally manage to get rid of it? Could you please walk again thru the steps in case I missed something? Thanks a lot

Comment: @Eduardo this is the script I ended up using to install and run kiosk apps through Google Chrome: https://gist.github.com/Enijar/30572e82b4cbf2e155c6d67a39bbfd02/

Comment: Thanks for the followup, but I have finally solved it. Just for the record, in my case the problem was that despite the fact that I was indeed using Ubuntu 18.04 (which I thought according to every reference I found was using gnome), it turned to be that it came preinstalled with unity (actual unity, not gnome made to look like unity). So, all the extensions did nothing. Once I realized this, I just removed unity and stuck with gnome, where the extensions did what they were meant to. Problem solved. In any case thank you and best regards.