# Disable ALL touchscreen gestures (not just multitouch) in Ubuntu or enable click-on-touch mode

Tags: chromium, touchscreen

We use Ubuntu 20.04 with Gnome 3.36.8 with x11 window system.
We wish to use a webapplication/website in Chromium with EETI touchscreen.
Usually we can use the touchscreen driver to set the touch controller to ''click on touch'' mode in Windows with the eGalax drivers, in Linux (we use eGalaxTouchManager-for LINUX_v2.5.7413.L-x-1.) this however doesn't work, in click to touch mode all touch input stops working. So the only way is to use it in normal mode.

In normal mode, we start Chromium in Kiosk mode fullscreen on startup.
We have already disabled multitouch via the driver and also via:
[Ubuntu 18.04 Touchscreen Kiosk – Disable Multi-Touch Gestures](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1065856/ubuntu-18-04-touchscreen-kiosk-disable-multi-touch-gestures)

However, we can STILL escape Chromium by swiping from the top border down, it will exit Chromium fullscreen and just show it windowed.

Is there a way disable ALL touch gestures possible: no more swiping up, down left or right with 1 finger, or force Ubuntu to handle touch input with ''click on touch'' mode, so no scrolling, just be able to press buttons in a web interface?

We wish to be able to escape chromium (with keyboard/teamviewer remotely) but otherwise, it always has to run in fullscreen mode and the touchscreen should in now way be ever able to escape it.

So anyone come across a way to kill all touch functionality except basic clicks on touch?

Comment: YES, very good question I travel by bus and its jumps in combination with multitouch drive me crazy... :-)