# Ubuntu Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS Touchscreen – Disable Multi-Touch Gestures

Tags: 22.04, gestures

I'm running a touchscreen through local python.

The problem I have is with the multi-touch gestures.
The gestures I would like to disable 3 and 4 touch gestures. The application should be impossible to close by user. (current These gestures allow users to exit the python application).

My question is, how do I disable these multi-touch gestures?

Edit: I've recorded a video demonstration of the multi-touch gesture.

LINK: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2Suu-rCi-1U&feature=share

HELP ME !!

I've tried this link [Ubuntu 18.04 Touchscreen Kiosk – Disable Multi-Touch Gestures](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1065856/ubuntu-18-04-touchscreen-kiosk-disable-multi-touch-gestures)
however i had the error:

gnome-shell-extension-tool: error: no such option: -i

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this extension? Others have reported it works.

https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/4049/disable-gestures-2021/

Comment: It worked, now i am having other problem i Would like to turn right matrix touch but show                                                           error:WARNING: running xinput against an Xwayland server. See the xinput man page for details. Do you know about it ?